# AngularJs ng-repeat - blank drop down when select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="selectedProduct='0'" ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-change="GetProduct(selectedProduct)">
<option value="0" selected>Add New</option>
<option ng-repeat="p in allProducts" value="{{p.id}}">{{p.name}}</option>
</select>
```

this is my javascript code

```
 $scope.GetProduct = function (productId) {
        if (productId > 0) {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Admin/GetSelectedProduct',
                data: { productId: productId }
            }).then(function successCallBack(successResponce) {
                $scope.products = successResponce.data;
                $scope.selectedProduct = $scope.products.id;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
        }
    };
```

when I selecting the products dropdown, properly load the data into the form, but products dropdown set blank.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDfHy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is id of the product integer? If yes then you should use `ng-value` instead of using simple `value`.

```
<option ng-repeat="p in allProducts" ng-value="p.id">{{p.name}}</option>
```

Try this one. It is just a work around. Please let me know if it is not solve your problem.